# using data from one column as part of an update for another column using Pandas from a very large csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a very large CSV file, where I generate a URL by using data from one column [c] and update the corresponding column cell [f] with the new information. Although I program a lot in Python, I don't use Pandas that often, so I am unsure as to where to handle this problem.

F is the final output, so I am using the C column as an image name, the of the URL is the same.

```
| c       | f                          |
| ------- | -------------------------- |
| 2134    | http://url.com/2134.jpg    |
| 3e32    | http://url.com/3e32.jpg    |
| jhknh   | http://url.com/jhknh.jpg   |
| 12.12.3 | http://url.com/12.12.3.jpg |
```

I have searched but I have not been able to find an implementable solution. I know, I probably would have to use `chunksize` for this, as there could be upward of 20000 records.

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated. I have looked and tried a few things but I am unable to come up with a solution.

Thank you in advance

~ E

Comment: F has an old URL, which I can delete before doing any updating.

Comment: @ Michael Szczesny the URL will be hardcoded in my python script, so the only variable will be the image name that will be coming from the C column. So `http://url.com/<c_column_cell>.jpg'

Comment: Then `df['f'] = 'http://url.com/' + df.c + '.jpg'` works with pandas. Assuming `df` is your dataframe.

Comment: @Michael Szczesny that I understand, but there are more than 20,000 records, do I iterate through each under 'chunksize'?

Comment: With only 20000 records you don't need to chunk your dataframe. And no iteration needed: `pandas` iterates over all records in a dataframe on its own.

Comment: @Michael Szczesny, I had not seen your question. The size of the file will continue to expand, so I wasn't sure about memory management, but thank you for letting me know about Panda being able to handle that amount of records and the iteration.

Answer (score 3):

Load your CSV file into a dataframe and update column 'f'

```
df = pd.read_csv('yourdatafile.csv')
df['f'] = 'http://url.com/' + df.c + '.jpg'
df
```

Output

```
         c                           f
0     2134     http://url.com/2134.jpg
1     3e32     http://url.com/3e32.jpg
2   jhnkhk   http://url.com/jhnkhk.jpg
3  12.12.1  http://url.com/12.12.1.jpg
```

---

If your records don't fit in memory you can chunk your data and append every chunk to a new file.

```
header = True
for chunk in pd.read_csv('yourdatafile.csv', chunksize=1000):
    chunk['f'] = 'http://newurl.com/' + chunk.c + '.jpg'
    chunk.to_csv('newdata.csv', mode='a+', index=False, header=header)
    header = False
```

Comment: that was exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: The `header = True` on top of the `for loop`, I did not use it and it worked. Could you elaborate a bit on that? thank you again.

Comment: I wanted a header as the first line in the new CSV file, but no other headers for each appended chunk. This is one way to achieve that.

Comment: The test file size I use was smaller than the `chunksize` so I didn't notice. When importing the file `pd.read_csv('yourdatafile.csv', header=0, chunksize=1000):` I imagine this doesn't accomplish what you want otherwise you would have used it.